# Reading a files and getting data from it

Tags: jupyter-notebook, networkx

I am quite new to Networkx, so I am experimenting with its various graphing functions

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('Employee.txt', delimiter="\t")
G
```

when i run for **G** it gives
<networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f0f706a1898>

what does this line means and numder(0xxxxxxxx)

how to get graph from this data.
how to see what inside the **G**,what does it contain.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down `<network.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f0f706a1898>`. The `network.classes.graph.Graph` part means that the variable `G` contains an instance of `network.classes.graph.Graph`. The `0x7f0f706a1898` part indicates where the variable `G` is stored in memory (though you probably won't need to know where it's stored). Anyway, there are a couple ways to see what's inside the variable `G`. If you want a list of the edges, the following code could tell you:

```
list(G.edges(data=True))
```

---

EDIT: In response to your comment, NetworkX is not designed to visualize graphs. This is what it says in it's documentation:

```
NetworkX provides basic functionality for visualizing graphs,
but its main goal is to enable graph analysis rather than perform graph visualization.
In the future, graph visualization functionality may be removed from NetworkX
or only available as an add-on package.
```

It does, however, support `matplotlib`. An example implementation could be as follows (you'll need to get `matplotlib` from `pip` first though):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

---

Check out the [NetworkX Documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot !
How can we draw the graph using data 'G'
So. now I wanted to see 'G' in graphical from.
nx.draw(G) is not working neither nx.draw_networkx(G).